# DevOps repo create event

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

is there a way how to listen DevOps repo events about repo creation.
Idea is to automate pipeline creation right after when a repo is created and it has a pipeline directory.

Answer (score 0):

DevOps doesn't have such a built-in method to achieve your requirements:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops

But you can do something like this：

1， Create a time trigger azure function to capture all of the repo in your project.

2,  Compare the current repos and previous repos each time with the last.

3, Create pipeline when you found the new repo created.